# JavaScript, clicking button activates parent event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons on my page that I use to try new things. Both of them use the "onclick" linked to a different JS function.
For some reason the second one activates both? And I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link HREF="styleTest.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Serif:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        <title>TEST</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="page">


        <div class="nav-container" onclick="hamburger(this)">
            
            <div class="ham-container">
                <div class="hamburger-1"></div>
                <div class="hamburger-2"></div>
                <div class="hamburger-3"></div>
            </div> 

            <div class="nav-bar">
                <a>Home</a>     
                <a>Services</a>     
                <a>About</a>    
                <a>Projects</a>
            </div>



            <div class="button-test">
                <button onclick="clickTest()">CLICK ME</button>
                <h1>Test text</h1>
            </div>

        </div>


    </body>
```

And the two JS functions:

```
function hamburger(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
  }

var i =0

function clickTest() {
  i++;
  console.log(i)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Events bubble upwards, so you need to cancel events manually if you don't want them to bubble up

Comment: Read [this article about events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#bubbling_example) on MDN.

Comment: The button that calls the `clickTest` function onClick is nested inside of the div that also calls the `hamburger` function onClick. That's why they're both getting called.

Comment: I also strongly recommend to learn about the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method over the outdated *inline event handlers*.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thank you! This helped me fix the issue and learn something new.

Comment: @ThomasDoll-Datema seems like a new and unrelated issue. Please open up a new question for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of a concept known as **Bubbling** in DOM .

**When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors.**

Try playing around with this snippet below .

```html
<style>
  body * {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
</style>

<form onclick="alert('form')">FORM
  <div onclick="alert('div')">DIV
    <p onclick="alert('p')">P</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

A click on the inner `<p>` first runs onclick:

**On that `<p>`.**

**Then on the outer `<div>`.**

**Then on the outer `<form>`.**

**And so on upwards till the document object.**

*Please refer this page for more clarity : [Link](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)*

Answer (score 2):

When you trigger an event on an element, it will sequentially be triggered for its father, for its grandfather... all the way to the last parent element. Often we don't see this behaviour happening because often we have one event listener in an elements' family.

But if the triggered element is inside a parent that has an event listener for the same event, like in your case, both of them will be triggered. However you can prevent this behaviour with the help of `stopPropagation` method, this way:

```js
function clickTest(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  i++;
  console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way event listeners works is that when you have a nested object
(For example button inside a div)
And both of them has event listeners , when you click on the inner element (button) the event listener of the `button` will first be fired before the parent event listener

To solve this, you have to stop the propagation using this code

```
<button onclick="clickTest(event)">CLICK ME</button>
```

And the script

```
  function clickTest(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  i++;
  console.log(i)
}
```